# How to run gunicorn from a folder that is not the django project folder

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, supervisord

I git cloned a project in my home folder, let's call it `/home/telessaude`. So the project root is located at `/home/telessaude/telessaude_branch_master`

If I am inside the Django project home folder ( /home/telessaude/telessaude_branch_master ) and issue a gunicorn comman such as

`gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 telessaude.wsgi_dev:application --reload --timeout 900`

gunicorn starts and works just fine. However ... if I try to run the same command on one directory above ( /home/telessaude ), I get the following error:

```
telessaude@ubuntu:~$ gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 telessaude.wsgi_dev:application --reload --timeout 900
[2017-03-22 16:39:28 +0000] [10405] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2017-03-22 16:39:28 +0000] [10405] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (10405)
[2017-03-22 16:39:28 +0000] [10405] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2017-03-22 16:39:28 +0000] [10410] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10410
[2017-03-22 16:39:28 +0000] [10410] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named telessaude.wsgi_dev
```

I also tried running gunicorn in my home folder with

`gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 telessaude_branch_master.telessaude.wsgi_dev:application --reload --timeout 900`

and

`gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 /home/telessaude/telessaude_branch_master/telessaude.wsgi_dev:application --reload --timeout 900`

but none of them also worked. Can someone tell me how to fix this? I need to run gunicorn from any folder, because I must add it as a "command" parameter to supervisor.

I'm not using a virtual enviromnment.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can use the `chdir` flag for Gunicorn to change to the project directory before executing your command.

```
gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /home/telessaude/telessaude_branch_master telessaude.wsgi_dev:application --reload --timeout 900
```

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck because of not been able to specify the proper command from a systemd service file. The --chdir option made the trick!

Comment: If you are using a config file, the same is true - i.e. in your dev.py file (in my case), specify a variable called chdir and set it equal to the path you want it to change to.

Answer (score 1):

**You should add your django app to the Python Path.**

In latest gunicorn, you can try this:

If the root path of django project is `/usr/local/src/djangoapp/`.

The `settings.py` path would default to `/usr/local/src/djangoapp/djangoapp/settings.py`.

```
gunicorn \
-c /usr/local/src/djangoapp/gunicorn_config.py \
--env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djangoapp.settings \
--pythonpath '/usr/local/src/djangoapp' \
djangoapp.wsgi:application
```

- **-c** config file path
- **--env** module path of the settings.py in your django project
- **--pythonpath** add your project path to Python Path [settings.html#pythonpath](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#pythonpath)

`--env` and `--pythonpath` are required.

> **Relative Path also be fine!**