# How to run gunicorn on a file in directory?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a flask application which uses application factory, and I can run gunicorn as `gunicorn "run:create_app()"` and this work fine.

However, I want to run it from it's parent directory, something like `gunicorn "application.run:create_app"` or `gunicorn "application/run:create_app"`

How to do this without --chdir?

Comment: why don't you just `cd` into the directory and run it from there?

Comment: is there a cleaner way to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42966708/3612571

Answer (score 7):

You already listed the pattern that should work- that argument is a `full dotted path` to a python module, plus a variable from that module that is an app object. So if we had a file `parent_dir/myproject/uwsgi.py` with the contents

```
from application import create_app
app = create_app()
```

we could run gunicorn like

```
# From myproject
gunicorn uwsgi:app
# from parent_dir
gunicorn myproject.uwsgi:app
```

Now, the problem I suspect you are seeing, is that dotted path notation requires the parent directory to be a python package- which means you need to have an `__init__.py` file in myproject. Otherwise the interpreter will not look inside that folder for python files to make them importable.

Python will look inside any directory that is on its PYTHONPATH. From there, any modules will be top level, and any directories with an `__init__.py` file will be packages. The default behavior is to add the current directory to the PYTHONPATH variable. So with the following structure

```
foldera
    packagea
        __init__.py
        modulea.py
folderb
    packageb
        __init__.py
        moduleb.py
folderc
    packagec
         modulec.py
```

From `foldera` you could do `import packagea.modulea` but not `import packageb.moduleb`. from the folder `packagea` you could do `import modulea` but not `import packagea.modulea` (the package isn't on the path!). From `folderc` you couldn't import ANY of these modules- there aren't any packages or modules on the PYTHONPATH. If you did set `export PYTHONPATH=foldera:folderb:folderc:$PYTHONPATH`, you could import `packagea.modulea` AND `packageb.moduleb`. You still couldn't import `modulec` or `modulea` or `moduleb` without the full dotted path.

Comment: the parent directory is a python package, but it does not work with dotted path.

Comment: The dot solved my problem, thanks!