# No module named 'app.settings' error when running app on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am this error when I try to run my app on heroku. I have no idea what's causing it

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deploytest.settings'
>   2020-05-15T21:02:25.372974+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-15 21:02:25 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
>   2020-05-15T21:02:25.542793+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-15 21:02:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
>   2020-05-15T21:02:25.542795+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-05-15 21:02:25 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn deploytest.deploytest.wsgi
```

I get the same error when my procfile is

```
web: gunicorn deploytest.wsgi
```

wsgi.py:

```py
"""
WSGI config for deploytest project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'deploytest.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

settings.py

```py
"""
Django settings for deploytest project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '<key>'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIES_SECURE = True


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['heroku']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'deploy.apps.DeployConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'deploytest.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'deploytest.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

my file structure is what you would expect of any typical django project. so settings.py and wsgi.py are both in the deploytest/deploytest directory. I have no idea what is causing this.

**Update:**

Putting my git inside deploytest/ did help out. I got the site working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to deploy `deploytest/` in such a way that you can see other apps too in root.
What I mean is do not upload this folder

```
deploytest/deploytest
```

If you do not understand what I mean ask.

Then use this `Procfile`

```
web: gunicorn deploytest.wsgi --log-file -
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by using the --chdir flag for gunicorn inside of my Procfile.
So in this scenario I believe the following would work: `web: gunicorn --chdir deploytest deploytest.wsgi`

[How to run gunicorn from a folder that is not the django project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961409/how-to-run-gunicorn-from-a-folder-that-is-not-the-django-project-folder)